# Retain radio button selection after submit - PHP

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am experiencing an issue with radio buttons present on my page, can anyone tell me why it wont retain its selection after the user has pressed submit?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
if(!empty($_POST['diet']))
?>

...

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<strong>Dietary Requirements:</strong>
<br><br>
Vegetarian <input type="radio" name="diet" <?php if (isset($_POST['diet']) && $_POST['diet']=="Vegetarian") echo "checked";?> value="Vegetarian">
<br><br>
Vegan <input type="radio" name="diet" <?php if (isset($_POST['diet']) && $_POST['diet']=="Vegan") echo "checked";?> value="Vegan">
<br><br><br>

...

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Confirmation page:

```
<b>Dietary Requirements: </b>
<br><br><?php if(isset($_SESSION['diet'])) echo $_SESSION['diet']; ?>
```

I have another set of radio buttons below the dietary requirements, which functions and retains its value fine after submit, so I dont understand why the dietary requirement radio buttons arent working.

Here is the functioning radio buttons for clarity:

```
<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">
<br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: What's your problem/ question now? Do you want to echo the value of the radio buttons? Or do you want to have the radio button still checked after submit the form?

Comment: I would like them to still be checked after submit is clicked

Comment: Hope my answer helps you! (The echo is for demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['diet']))
            $_SESSION['diet'] = $_POST['diet'];
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['diet']))
        echo $_SESSION['diet']
?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <strong>Dietary Requirements:</strong>
    <br><br>
    Vegetarian <input type="radio" name="diet" <?php if (isset($_POST['diet']) && $_POST['diet']=="Vegetarian") echo "checked";?> value="Vegetarian">
    <br><br>
    Vegan <input type="radio" name="diet" <?php if (isset($_POST['diet']) && $_POST['diet']=="Vegan") echo "checked";?> value="Vegan">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be working however on my confirmation page which the user is taken to after they press submit, it isnt being echoed :( Any idea why this might be? I can update my question if necessary

Comment: @JamesPatterson check that this is in a form tag and the attr. action and method are set right! Also look if you direct to another page! Otherwise show more code where your using it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question with the needed(?) code, let me know if this is enough to work out why the dietary requirements arent being echoed.

Comment: @JamesPatterson As you can see in my example you have to use `$_POST` so just copy the 2 input lines from my answer and it should work

Comment: sorry, was meant to include this in my update, I have already applied those two input lines but still nothing is eachoed on the confirmation page :(

Comment: @JamesPatterson You never direct your page to another page! Also you never assign a value to the session array!