# Radio button set's array created dynamically with echo in php. How to get their values?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, radio-button

I've created a php page which retrieves question and options(as MCQ's) from the database and in that Radio buttons are created dynamically using `echo()`
The name for each radio button group is assigned into an array from which one by one index's value is set to the `name` attribute.
Example:

```
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);//gets the number of questions
$radiogrp_name=array();

for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++){    //creating array of names for each set of radio buttons
    $radiogrp_name[$i]="q".$i;
}
$i=0;
while(($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && ($i<$numrows)){
    echo $myrow["q_no"].". ";
    echo $myrow["ques"]."<br><br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='a'/>".$myrow["A"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='b'/>".$myrow["B"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='c'/>".$myrow["C"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='d'/>".$myrow["D"]."<br><br><br>";
    $i++;
    }
```

How would I get the selected radio buttons and set them into a `SESSION` variable? Can anyone help with this? Or any other way to implement this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Until now I do not see that you select anything in the coding so you mean the ones that have been clicked by the user right?

Comment: Yes. I have a submit button down there.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082153/retain-radio-button-selection-after-submit-php

Comment: Okay I'll try it that way and return.

Comment: Can we write php code under php that too in echo() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page that the form is POST'ed to you are going to need to look through the `$_POST` array and strip out the relevant answers. Ideally you would have a list of expected indexes to drive that page, but if not you could just try to pattern match the indexes.

Something like:

```
$results = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match("/q(\d{1,3})/", $key, $matches)){
        $results[$matches[1]] = $value;
    }
}
```

results would then contain an array of values indexed by the numeral in `name="q#"` and you would just set it to the session or do with it whatever you need.

**EDIT**
by the way, you'll need to wrap your string inclusion in curlies since it is an array.

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='{$radiogrp_name[$i]}' value='d'/>"
```

Comment: What does wrapping them into curlies do?It worked anyway..??

Comment: @Diksha Oh, it's because the indexes don't have quotes... my bad. I always wrap arrays just to be safe. Reviewing the docs, only quoted keys technically need the complex syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php . Oh well, I'm glad it works! ^_^

Comment: Ohkay... Thank you for letting me know that :)